# How to bind Blazorise Multi-Select AutoComplete to Model

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have a Blazor page in which the user can select multiple employees using autocomplete.

[image]

```
@page "/Multi"
@uisng removed

<Autocomplete TItem="GraphUser"
              TValue="string"
              Data="@users"
              TextField="@(( item ) => item.DisplayName)"
              ValueField="@(( item ) => item.DisplayName)"
              Placeholder="Search..."
              Multiple
              @bind-SelectedValues="_multipleSelectionData"
              @bind-SelectedTexts="_multipleSelectionTexts">
</Autocomplete>

@code {

    [Inject] public IGraphService GraphService { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GraphUser> users = new List<GraphUser>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = await GraphService.GetUsers();
        _multipleSelectionData = new List<string>();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    List<string> _multipleSelectionData;
    List<string> _multipleSelectionTexts = new();
}
```

Now I need to bind this to a real field, and am totally at a loss on how to do that. The code sample below is what I need to replace. I need to bind the values the user selects to "@ApprovalFlowForm.Other".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Eventually I would like to just make the select part a component which I can call in and dynamically bind to different fields, but want to get this thing working first.

```
<Label Display="Display.Flex"> Other </Label>

<Select TValue="string" @bind-SelectedValues="@ApprovalFlowForm.Other" Multiple>

@{foreach (var item in GraphUserOptions)
    {
    <SelectItem Value="@item.Value">@item.Text</SelectItem>
    }
}
</Select>
```

My question was not clear enough.

Below is the code that I am replacing:

```
<div class="create-approval-flow-drop-down">
                            <Label Display="Display.Flex"> Director </Label>
                            <Select TValue="string" @bind-SelectedValues="@ApprovalFlowForm.Director" Multiple>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var item in GraphUserOptions)
                                    {
                                        <SelectItem Value="@item.Value">@item.Text</SelectItem>
                                    }
                                }
                            </Select>
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ApprovalFlowForm.Director)" />
                        </div>
```

The key here is the line

> @bind-SelectedValues="@ApprovalFlowForm.Director"

The the previous code that "works" the selected Values are being bound to the Director field in the form "ApprovalFlow". I am changing the way this field is accessed to use a blazorise autocomplete multi-select. That way the user can use type ahead and just enter a few letters of someone name and get a subsetted list. The current drop down just presents a list of literally 2,000 people that users must scroll through.

I was able to get the code to work so that the user can use type ahead, but the last step, the step that I thought would be easy, was simply to bind it to the field in the model so we can write it to the database.

I tried this

```
@bind-SelectedValues="@ApprovalFlowForm.LocManager"
```

but when I do so I get the error "Cannot convert from systems.collections.generic.ireadonlyList(strong) to System.Collections.Generic.List(String)".

I imagine this is telling me exactly what to do, but I cannot figure out what that is.

Thanks.

Comment: "Now I need to bind this to a real field": Could you explain this further? What is a "real" field? The code snippets seem to have working code and I'm a bit confused on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Dimitris, I have added some additional comments about what I am trying to do.  I hope this gives you enough information to assist. Thank you for much for looking at my questions.

Comment: It's a lot more clear now. You could change `LocManager` type from `IReadOnlyList<string>` to `List<string>`. You can't bind with a read-only collection because the component has to be able to update it when user selections change.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `LocManager` type from `IReadOnlyList<string>` to `List<string>`. You can't bind with a read-only collection because the component has to be able to update it when user selections change.

If it's not possible to change `LocManager` type then you can do manual event binding like this:

```
<Autocomplete
    ...   
    SelectedValues="@ApprovalFlowForm.LocManager.ToList()"
    SelectedValuesChanged="OnSelectedValuesChanged">

</Autocomplete>

@code {
    private void OnSelectedValuesChanged(List<string> values)
    {
        ApprovalFlowForm.LocManager = values;
    }
}
```

If you want to bind autocomplete to a string property you can do it like this:

```
<Autocomplete
    ...   
    SelectedValues="@GetValues()"
    SelectedValuesChanged="OnSelectedValuesChanged">

</Autocomplete>

@code {
    private List<string> GetValues()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApprovalFlowForm.XXXX))
        {
            return ApprovalFlowForm.XXXX
                .Split(",")
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectedValuesChanged(List<string> values)
    {
        ApprovalFlowForm.XXXX = string.Join(",", values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dimistris, this has helped me understand the issue better, but I am still having an issue. The field in the form, @ApprovalFlow.XXXX is actually a string separated by commas. So a multiple value would be "John Kennedy, Richard Nixon" and so on. I don't know why it was done this way, but it was. So I suppose what I need to do is to make a list when the user is selecting the value, but then make a string separated by values when it is saved to the database. When a new item is created I should just have a blank? I struggled with this for several hours over the weekend and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hi, added an example of how you can bind autocomplete with a string that contains comma separated values.